# Using thing-at-point as initial input for bookmark-jump with bookmark+ and helm mode

Tags: helm, bookmarks, completing-read

I am using `bookmark+` and `helm` mode.

Debugging a large Fortran code base, I have created some bookmarks that has the same name as some of the Fortran subroutines. Now, I would like to put the cursor on the subroutine name and press `C-x r b` to run `bookmark-jump` to the given function (given at point). As it works now, a Helm buffer with name `"bookmark-jump"` is shown, and the minibuffer prompt is shown as `"Jump to bookmark:"`.

I would like to have the `thing-at-point` filled in as initial input after the minibuffer prompt. How can this be done?

Note: I have looked at the `bookmark+-1.el` source code and found a variable `bmkp-default-bookmark-name`, but that does not allow the initial input to be set as far as I can see.

Comment: Define "*initial input*" in your context. `bmkp-default-bookmark-name` is used in `bookmark-jump` as the `DEFAULT` argument to `completing-read`.  If you use `bookmark-jump` interactively then just use `M-n` to retrieve the default value. But if you use something (e.g., Helm) other than `bookmark-jump` (interactively) then check with what that other thing does - whether and how it uses the default value.

Comment: Googling a bit (not much) shows `helm-sources-using-default-as-input` and `helm-maybe-use-default-as-input`. Maybe one of those, or some other Helm setting, can help you. Or maybe a Helm users will provide a simple answer of how to get Helm to insert the default value as the initial input.

Comment: (If you were using [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), you would need only to customize (or bind locally) option [`icicle-default-value`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-default-value), to get the default value inserted as initial input. In fact, 4 of the 6 possible values for that option cause such insertion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible workaround by advicing `helm--completing-read-default`:

```
(advice-add 'helm--completing-read-default
            :around
            #'my-set-initial-helm-completing-read-input-as-thing-at-point)

(defun my-set-initial-helm-completing-read-input-as-thing-at-point
    (helm-completion-function
     prompt collection
     &optional
     predicate require-match
     orig-initial-input hist def
     inherit-input-method)
  (let ((initial-input orig-initial-input))
    (when (string= prompt "Jump to bookmark: ")
      (setq initial-input (thing-at-point 'symbol t)))
    (apply helm-completion-function
           prompt collection
           predicate require-match
           initial-input hist def
           inherit-input-method)))
```

**Edit**:

In case I would like to jump to a bookmark which name is
not given at point, I created a special function `my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump` which I bound to `C-x j j`. Then I can use `C-x r b` as the normal `bookmark-jump`:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map "j" bmkp-jump-map)
(define-key bmkp-jump-map "j" #'my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump)
(defvar my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump nil
  "Whether to insert thing at point as initial input into Helm completion buffer.")
(defun my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump()
  (interactive)
  (let ((my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump t))
    (call-interactively 'bookmark-jump)))
```

Finally, change this part in the advicing function `my-set-initial-helm-completing-read-input-as-thing-at-point` defined above:

```
(when (string= prompt "Jump to bookmark: ")
  (when my-thing-at-point-bookmark-jump
    (setq initial-input (thing-at-point 'symbol t))))
```

Comment: This sounds like something general, for Helm. Is there no general Helm way to tell Helm to *insert the default value* for completion, so that you don't have to do what you are doing in N specific cases?

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens in `(interactive)`:

```
(defun say-word (word)
  (interactive (list
                (read-string (format "word (%s): " (thing-at-point 'word))
                             nil nil (thing-at-point 'word))))
  (message "The word is %s" word))
```

This will set the word under point as default input.

I got it from here:

[Link to Question with Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646088/emacs-interactive-commands-with-default-value)

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting. Actually my bookmark name also contains the Fortran file name that the subroutine is in. So for example, if the cursor is located at the string `setup` in (buffer) file `init.f95` and the subroutine `setup` is defined in file `start.f95`, the bookmark name will be `setup:start.f95`. // Also, I would like to know how to bring up the helm buffer with the initial input set to `setup`. If I call `bookmark-jump` directly with `"setup:start.f95"` as an argument, the Helm buffer is not shown at all.

Comment: You could assemble your bookmark name (replace the last line by this):  `(message "The  is %s" (concat word ":" (buffer-name))))`. By this way you could also redefine the `(interactive)` default. But I cannot help you with `Helm` or `bookmark-jump`, sorry.

Comment: No problem :) Also note that `buffer-name` in your last comment will be `init.f95` and not `start.f95`, so that would not work.